# Is it possible to extend from any of 'n' defined interfaces and create a new child interface in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to extend from any of 3 defined interfaces and create a new one with its own properties.

E.g.:

```
interface IChild extends any(IFirst, ISecond, IThird) {
  ownVar1: string;
  ownVar2: number;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this.

N.B. I have used `any` here as just an example as to show that would like to use some similar keyword if available,

Comment: Do you want to extend all interfaces? `interface IChild extends IFirst, ISecond, IThird {}`

Comment: @John I'd like to extend any of them not all of them.

My gut feeling is it is not doable.

Comment: I don't know. Probably not? I would instead create `IParent` and let any of `IFirst`, `ISecond`, `IThird` extend `IParent`. Maybe you can achieve the same result using that technique instead? Just a thought.

Comment: Yeah. That will be a way. I like it.
But with the current scenario it won't fit into the codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the type you are looking for:

```js
interface A {
    a: 'a'
}
interface B {
    b: 'b'
}
interface C {
    c: 'c'
}

type UnionInterface = A | B | C;

type Child = UnionInterface & {
    ownVar1: string;
    ownVar2: number;
}


const x: Child = {
    ownVar1: 'hello',
    ownVar2: 42,
    a: 'a'
}

const y: Child = {
    ownVar1: 'hello',
    ownVar2: 42,
    b: 'b'
}

const z: Child = {
    ownVar1: 'hello',
    ownVar2: 42,
    c: 'c'
}
```

Please keep in mind, that in TS you can do smth like that:

```js
interface IChild extends A, B, C {

}
```

Bit it is mean that your IChild interface extends all properties from A,B,C.

If you want to extend a union type, A or B or C, you should use `types` instead `interfaces`

Comment: I was looking for this Union type. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to accomplish. Maybe you can add some more information about why. My first thought was that you wanted to use an Interface that is either `IFirst`, `ISecond` and so on. Then a function can take any of those as an argument, no matter the type (thus your `IChild`). If that is the case, I would instead create an `IParent` interface and let `IFirst`, `ISecond` and `IThird` extend `IParent`

```
interface IParent{}
interface IFirst extends IParent {}
interface ISecond extends IParent {}

// then do something like this
function foo(IParent myInterface){}

const first: IFirst = {};
const second: ISecond = {};

foo(first); // OK
foo(second); // OK
```